# Ionic 2 - Sticky header

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to create a sticky header in my app, which holds the value of the current block.

I retrieve the scroll position using this code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild(Content)
  content:Content;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // I want to trigger the listener during the scroll event
    this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.onPageScroll(data);
    });
  }

  onPageScroll(data) {
   console.log("top:", data['scrollTop'])
  }

  :
  :
```

In order to determine which element to show in the sticky header, I have at the end of each block a hidden element:

```
<div class="titleTag" style="display:none">{{event.title}}</div>
```

When I try to retrieve the position of these elements:

```
let titleTags = document.getElementsByClassName('titleTag');
for (let el of <any>titleTags) {
  console.log(" > offsetTop", el.offsetTop);
}
```

I get 0.

I tried also `offsetHeight` and `scrollTop`, both return 0 as well.

Any idea??

Comment: Have you tried `<ion-header>` ?  https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Header/

Comment: I have an `<ion-header>` element, which actually has a placeholder for the sticky title, but the problem is that I do not manage to get the next element to show!

Comment: Created a small directive for sticky ion-list-header: https://github.com/jonaszuberbuehler/ion-affix. Do you need sth like this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to directly get elements in Ionic 2/Angular 2 use [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html).

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';


//class..
constructor(public el:ElementRef){}

//in your function...
let titleTags =this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('titleTag');
for (let el of <any>titleTags) {
  console.log(" > offsetTop", el.offsetTop);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it neither works for me... I get 0. BTW, when I check (debugging) `el.`__proto__ I get: `HTMLDivElement {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLDivElement"}`. I checked also `offsetTop` of all ancestors, for all of them I get the same result - zero!